# Find velocity of ambulance from the observed frequencies?

Tags: doppler-effect

I have a problem where an ambulance with a siren is traveling past me (a stationary observer) at a constant velocity. When the ambulance is approaching, I measured the frequency at 1000 Hz and as it was going away from me, after it passed, I measured the frequency at 950 Hz. What is the velocity of the ambulance assuming the speed of sound is 340 m/s.

I have not been able to solve this problem as I do not have the source frequency and every sample problem I have found has the source frequency listed. And the source frequency is not exactly in between the 2 observed frequencies.

Comment: Think about it. You do have the source frequency.

Comment: Do you mean use 950 as the source and 1000 as the final the calculated being 2x the velocity of the ambulance? I will try it. Thanks.

Comment: From the problem you can write *two* equations. Then you can combine these two equations so as to cancel out the source frequency.

Comment: i agree with above comments by lemon and you should get about 87m/s as speed of ambulance..pl. check.

Comment: @MichaelE  did you try out  taking double the speed of ambulance...do you get a proper answer?

Comment: Using the frequencies as source and observed does not work and gives different results depending of which one is source and observed.

Comment: I did find a formula reference here: http://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?t=721840 which is V = (FHigh - FLow) / (FHigh + FLow * c  and it works for a sample problem found here: http://www.thermaxxjackets.com/doppler-effect-frequency-change/ so it appears to be accurate and gives me a result of 8.72 m/s for my problem. Now only to derive that formula. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for velocity from knowing the frequency approaching and leaving is:

$$V = \frac{(HiFreq - LoFreq)}{(HiFreq + LoFreq)} * c$$

**8.72 M/S** is the result using 1000 and 950 as the frequencies and 340 for velocity.

Now to derive this formula.
As clearly posted here: [enter link description here](http://www.thermaxxjackets.com/doppler-effect-frequency-change/) the formula for observed frequency for a stationary observer is:

$$ Fo = \frac{(c)}{(c -+ V)} * Fs$$
Where c is the speed of sound and V is negative when the source is approaching the observer and positive when going away from the observer.
This also means for the high frequency HiFreq use (-) and for LoFreq use (+).

Solve for source frequency:

$$ Fs = \frac{(c - V)}{c} * HiFreq = \frac{(c + V)}{c} * LoFreq$$

The (c)s cancel out and now solve for V.

$$c*HiFreq - V*HiFreq = c*LoFreq + V*LoFreq$$ continue with some algebra.
$$c*HiFreq - c*LoFreq = V*HiFreq + V*LoFreq$$
$$c*(HiFreq - LoFreq) = V*(HiFreq + LoFreq)$$ and finally.

$$V = \frac{(HiFreq - LoFreq)}{(HiFreq + LoFreq)} * c$$